# 2010 SharePoint Workflow to send empty field from Item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

Is it possible to create a workflow that will send email that contains empty column?

Ex: 
First Name - Empty Field 
Middle Name - Is Not Empty Field 
Last Name - Empty Field 
Address - Is Not Empty Field

Output:
Send Email( Content should be the empty fields only)
Missing First Name
Missing Last Name

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send email by keeping the empty field value in the body of the mail. 
but the email field should not empty.

if you want to keep the conditions on the fields to check empty, there is any if condition available in the workflow.

[image]